# getcwd() vs get_current_dir_name()?

Tags: c, linux, io

Is it better to use `getcwd(NULL, 0)` or `get_current_dir_name()` ? What is common practice ?

My uninformed guess is that a call to `getcwd(NULL, 0)` may be a better idea since it is possible that the PWD variable is not set...

Comment: And what makes you think that `getcwd` is a better idea than `get_current_dir_name` when `PWD` isn’t set?

Comment: @KonradRudolph The `man` implied that `get_current_dir_name` uses that variable but since you took the time to write a comment my newer guess is that both functions are and the `man` is poorly redacted and that they are equivalent.

Comment: Indeed. The man page is both *misleading* (it doesn’t mean that `get_current_dir_name` only works if `PWD` is set), and additionally *wrong* (at least in my tests, the value of `PWD` has *no* impact on the function’s value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it better to use `getcwd(NULL, 0)` or `get_current_dir_name()` ? What is common practice ?

### This is operating system specific. I guess you use Linux.

Then, read [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [getcwd(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html). Study the source code of its implementation in [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or in [musl libc](https://musl.libc.org/)

Notice that

- `getcwd` takes a buffer of a given known size. In practice, 256 bytes might be often enough, but in principle the buffer should be much bigger. See [sysconf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) and [pathconf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pathconf.3.html). Accepting `getcwd(NULL,0)` is an extension equivalent to `get_current_dir_name()` so uses `malloc` and could fail. My Debian computer has in `/usr/include/linux/limits.h` a macro definition `#define PATH_MAX 4096` (but 4096, when used as the size of some [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable), is a lot for a [call frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) of any recursive function; look also into [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)).
- `getwd` is obsolete since prone to buffer overflow. Don't use it in 2021.
- `get_current_dir_name` uses [malloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) which could fail.

AFAIK, [getcwd(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) should not use the `PWD` environment variable. It should work if you code your own `/sbin/init` using it

And sometimes, you can boot a Linux kernel running `/bin/bash` instead of `/sbin/init`. In such case, the `PWD` environment variable is not set. See [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

Of course, in most other programs, `PWD` is correctly set (e.g. by [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), whose source code you can study since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html))

My personal recommendation

- assume and document that your program won't run for file paths larger than e.g. 256 bytes (but be aware that [UTF 8 is everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) in 2021). This assumption could be false for file names which are generated with [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) strings or several [IPV6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) addresses, and you might want to use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) for `path` below.... so a near equivalent of `get_current_dir_name`. Don't forget to `free` it!
- code something like:

  ```
  char path[256];
  memset (path, 0, sizeof(path));
  if (getcwd(path, sizeof(path)) == NULL) {
    perror("getcwd");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // or abort()
  }
  ```

Of course, if you code an `init`-like program for some robot, this is not good enough. Robots on Mars might *generate* long path names!

Comment: OP isn’t asking about `getwd`, and they’re asking about `getcwd(NULL, 0)`, which has a  different specification and different semantics from what you’ve written.

Comment: Re your edit: actually it seems that at least *sometimes* the setting of `PWD` has absolutely no bearing on the value of either function call: it’s simply ignored, regardless of whether it’s set, unset, or set to a different value.

Comment: @chux: yes. Sorry, I am not a native English speaker (I am French, probably like the OP)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I believe that `PWD` is *never* used by `getcwd`

Comment: I believe that, too.  Each process's current working directory is part of that process's metadata, and is therefore maintained by the kernel.  I expect `getcwd()` and `get_current_dir_name()` both to rely on that metadata under all circumstances.

Comment: @Basile I agree, but it’s pure speculation on my part and I didn’t want to overreach. — I’m not really happy with your 256 path length recommendation: there’s *no* reason for this number, it’s woefully inadequate nowadays (even without UTF-8 it’s easy to exceed it). Even the (problematic) `PATH_MAX` constant is usually/often/always(?) set to 4096.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I am coding since 1974 and **I never heard of a real file name above 256 bytes** - did you got one in your life (in practice) ? Of course, in theory it could happen. File paths are often typed by humans (and those that are generated could be made smaller).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, surely you mean you haven't heard of a *file name* longer than 256 bytes.  Paths can of course chain an arbitrary number of these together, and it is pretty common for the results to be longer than 256 bytes.  I have seen more such paths than I can count in reasonable, active use.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I guess these file names have been generated. I am not patient enough to type 256 bytes file paths. My `xterm` has usually less than 128 columns, and even that is too wide for my eyes.

Comment: @Basile In my domain, deeply nested file paths are often auto-generated by data processing pipelines, and frequently contain UUID strings. But even for regular, “artisanal” paths, 256 characters are reached (not frequently, but on a regular basis) on my system. I just checked, and I found several.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I sometimes type very long paths with the assistance of filename completion, but I more often navigate through the directory tree with `cd` and use relative paths.  Occasionally I even use a graphical file browser.  Long paths do not create much of a usability issue as far as I am concerned.

Comment: There is, or could be, a macro `PATH_MAX` from POSIX [`<limits.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html), or you might need to use the [`pathconf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pathconf.html)
to get the actual limit for a particular path (or use `_POSIX_PATH_MAX` or perhaps `_XOPEN_PATH_MAX` to get a static limit).  There's no need to guess at a limit like 256.  Note that there's also `NAME_MAX` for the size of a name component.  POSIX has lower limits of 256 and 14, X/Open has 1024 and 256.